# Airflow `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator` does not respect `wait_until_finished = False`

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I try to run a simple DAG that asynchronously submits [beam python pipeline](https://github.com/MichaelDuemcke/minimal-reproducible-example-airflow-waiting-beam/blob/main/dummy_beam_dag.py#L33-L51) and the [sensor](https://github.com/MichaelDuemcke/minimal-reproducible-example-airflow-waiting-beam/blob/main/dummy_beam_dag.py#L53-L62) that waits for the pipeline completion, as suggested in airflow/beam [best practice](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataflow.html#asynchronous-execution).

According to the official airflow documentation, the Airflow operator should asynchronously submit the Beam job, where the `wait_for_the_beam_job` task is checking the status of the `submit_beam_job` and mark the sensor task as Done when the job finishes.

Unexpectedly, the beam is running synchronously. Have you any idea how can this issue be solved?
Here is my minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/MichaelDuemcke/minimal-reproducible-example-airflow-waiting-beam

Answer (score 1):

try by removing line

```py
result.wait_until_finish()
```

in https://github.com/MichaelDuemcke/minimal-reproducible-example-airflow-waiting-beam/blob/6f1fe87c1f71a56b3dc06adb7fa7c8d5889a68e0/dummy_beam_job.py#L47